# copy NSManagedObject to a new object in memory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a menu screen that populates with data from an NSManagedObject.  While this screen is up the user can enter in all sorts of values. etc.

The problem I am having is that I need to not alter the initial NSManagedObject used to populate the screen.  I need a copy that the user can alter instead because if they cancel out before everything is done, then what was the original and correct information gets corrupt by impartial data.

However, I am having issues implementing any kind of copy method or process inside my NSManagedObject because all of the properties are @dynamic.

If I just 'return self' in a copyWithZone method inside the NSManagedObject, would that properly copy everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a category to add a copy method to your custom NSManagedObject?

If your NSManagedObject was User, then create a new category User+copy.h/m where in you would add the copy method which would simply copy all the individual fields one by one.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to make your changes to the same NSManagedObject, but in a child NSManagedObjectContext. That way, if you need to discard the changes, you can just throw the child context away without affecting your main context or object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271464/how-do-i-create-a-child-nsmanagedobjectcontext).

Comment: im pretty new to coredata.  once I create a child context... how do I use it to access the object I want?

Comment: Take a look at [`-[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJIFIGA) - it lets you get an object with a known ID in a given context. Perhaps you can pull the ID from the object you wish to edit and ask for an object with that ID in your new child context.